# How to remove part of user entered values and append new values to an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search box and a suggestion box to show the suggestions.

Once users type something in the search box, the suggestions will appear then user is able to select one of the suggestions to be added to the search input box. After that user will be able to type other terms to receive the suggestions and so on.

I can show the suggestions and add the selected suggestion to the input box **but**

lets say user enters f then first is suggested and user choose it, then the input box will be f, first but it should be first only. if I reset the input I will lose the other search terms.

In short: I want to keep all values before the last semicolon and remove all those after the semicolon.

**code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectS(value){
        alert("clicked:" + value);
         var curr = $('#term').val();
            if(curr)
                 curr += ";";
            $('#term').val(curr + value);
    }
....

<s:form id="searchForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <s:textfield id="term" name="term" label="Search" onkeyup="find(this.value)"/>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Why did you ask this again? :) Guessing you realized it was not as simple as append. You need to use replace() and know what the user typed. Or you can use a library that does this for you.

Comment: @epascarello description is different, because I need to know how to remove the user entered words and add the new suggestion.

Comment: Check your id you use "#tern" try to use $('#term').val(curr + value);

Comment: So you have a list of multiple search terms separated by semi-colons?  So you don't want to clear the entire text box, just the text since the last semi-colon?

Comment: @AdamPlocher yes I want to keep all values before the last semicolon and remove all those after the semicolon.

Comment: Can you post your 'find' function?  I would like to see how you're parsing the new search term after the last semi-colon.  You should be able to use a substring of (#term).val() with that character count stripped off the end (or regex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is **Auto Complete** from Javascript UI

See http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple ...

it allows multiple select in search box.

if for some reason you dont want to use it.. you can use below code

```
 function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /;\s*/ );
    }

function selectS(value){
        alert("clicked:" + value);
         var curr = split($('#term').val());
         // remove the current input
          curr.pop();          
          // add the selected item
          curr.push( value );
         // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          curr.push( "" );

         $('#term').val(curr.join( "; " ););
    }
```

Comment: It is a good one but the problem is that, I am using struts2, and my input defined as <s:textfield> does it work on that as well?

Comment: its `<s:textfield>` on `server side`. `taghandlers` executed on `server side`.. when its render back `to client` its simple `HTML` again.. try to do `View source` and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

Learn basic regular expressions.

```
var text = "foo";
var str = "asdf;qwerty;g";
var newStr = str.replace(/(;)?[^;]+$/,"$1" + text);
console.log(newStr);
```

Same thing could be done with split and join

```
var text = "foo";
var str = "asdf;qwerty;g";
var parts = str.split(";");
parts.pop();
parts.push(text);
var newStr = parts.join(";");
console.log(newStr);
```